# Drupal 7 - using theme_intendation

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm trying to use [theme_intendation()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_indentation/7) in the same way as drupal menus do. When I try using  `print_r(theme('intendation', array('size' => 3)));` I get nothing.

Shouldn't `print_r()` show three intendation divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Drupal, but it looks like you have misspelled "indentation".

Comment: It's best to add this kind of response as a comment below the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Wow, kind of embarrassing. But you're right of course, it works when spelled right :)

Comment: @codeinthehole Unless, of course, it really is the answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As reported from the documentation, the function name is `theme_indentation()`. This means your code should similar to the following one:

```
$output = theme('indentation', array('size' => 3));
```